# Instagram InstagramCaption not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, hook, instagram, instagram-api

I have below code for sharing article on Instagram.

```
-(void) shareInstagram {
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
    {
        UIImage *instaImage = mImg.image;
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(instaImage); //convert image into .png format.
        NSLog(@"imageData.leeee===%d", imageData.length);
        if (imageData.length<=100) {
            [self.view makeToast:localize(@"instaErr2") duration:2.0 position:@"bottom"];
        } else {
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];//create instance of NSFileManager
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //create an array and store result of our search for the documents directory in it
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //create NSString object, that holds our exact path to the documents directory
            NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insta.igo"]]; //add our image to the path
            [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil]; //finally save the path (image)
            NSLog(@"image saved");

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 , 0, 0);
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
            [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            NSString *fileNameToSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/insta.igo"];
            NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameToSave];
            NSLog(@"jpg path %@",jpgPath);
            NSString *newJpgPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file://%@",jpgPath];
            NSLog(@"with File path %@",newJpgPath);
            NSURL *igImageHookFile = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:newJpgPath];
            NSLog(@"url Path %@",igImageHookFile);

            self.documentController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            self.documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile usingDelegate:self];
            self.documentController=[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:igImageHookFile];

            NSString *globalString;

            if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"PoPinFrom"] isEqualToString:@"user"]) {
                globalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @ %@\n\nhttp://egkw.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?id=%@\n\niPhone : %@\n\nAndroid : %@", [[productDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Title"], localize(@"appName"), [[productDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Id"], localize(@"appStoreLink"), localize(@"playStoreLink")];
            } else {
                globalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @ %@\n\nhttp://egkw.com/ArticleDetail.aspx?id=%@\n\niPhone : %@\n\nAndroid : %@", [[productDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Title"], localize(@"appName"), [[productDetailsArray objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Id"], localize(@"appStoreLink"), localize(@"playStoreLink")];
            }

            globalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n#EGKW", globalString];
            NSLog(@"insta==globalString==%@", globalString);
            self.documentController.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:globalString, @"InstagramCaption", nil];
            // self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:globalString forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
            [self.documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView: self.view animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog (@"Instagram not found");
        DTAlertView *myAl = [DTAlertView alertViewWithTitle:localize(@"err001") message:localize(@"instaErr") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:localize(@"dismiss") positiveButtonTitle:nil];
        [myAl setDismissAnimationWhenButtonClicked:DTAlertViewAnimationSlideTop];
        [myAl showWithAnimation:DTAlertViewAnimationSlideBottom];
    }
}
```

This code was working fine earlier. However when I noticed, I see that caption is not showing in Instagram. After research I changed

```
 self.documentController.annotation=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:globalString, @"InstagramCaption", nil];
```

to

```
self.documentController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:globalString forKey:@"InstagramCaption"];
```

But still it is not working.

***Any idea what is going wrong?***

*Did Instagram changed any policy like Facebook?*

Comment: I am running into exact same issue, in my case, I'm trying a hashtag, but no avail.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu : I  think Instagram changed its policy like Facebook but Instagram have not posted.. So not  sure whether this is bug or change in policy...

Comment: Just saw that. Sad to see this while implementing this exact functionality.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instagram has now removed the filling in of the caption field using the interaction controller.

See this blog post from them

[Instagram developer blog](http://developers.instagram.com/post/125972775561/removing-pre-filled-captions-from-mobile-sharing)

Comment: *sharing channel often feel spammy*, ***is something odd from Instagram***

Comment: Is there any recourse? I have an app that is heavily dependent on the caption being sent. That app is now completely worthless...So I'm hoping there's another way.