# iOS Swift - Share on Instagram with captions

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, uidocumentinteraction

I am able to successfully share an image on **Instagram** using the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, but the `InstagramCaption` key won't work. This is my code:

```
self.controller = UIDocumentInteractionController()
// controller.delegate = self

self.controller.URL = fileUri

// HERE, the caption won't appear.
self.controller.annotation = NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: "my caption", "InstagramCaption")

self.controller.UTI = "com.instagram.exclusivegram"
self.controller.presentOpenInMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

see question [Instagram Caption not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915122/instagram-instagramcaption-not-working/31917013#31917013)

This feature has been removed from the iPhone hook

Comment: Yeah we were pretty surprised to. I think it's because they are preparing their ads api which will have some posting functionality, but at the moment its only available to ad partners according to the news reports I've seen on it