# How to share image/video on Instagram with caption?

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, share

I need to share an image or a video on **Instagram** with a caption.
I tried different methods like [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller?changes=_9) and [iPhone Hooks](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/), but none of this worked for me.
I have already found similar questions on SO but they are all dated and no longer working.
Does anyone know a method already tested and working?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11501350/4061501)

Comment: Yes, I did, but it does not work

Comment: have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929940/ios-swift-share-on-instagram-with-captions)

Comment: @KetanOdedra Yes, I did. So you confirm that it is no longer possible to share an image with a precompiled caption?

Comment: actually you can put your post and  story in instagram but no idea about sharing .

Comment: Did you got  a solution?